# tkinter AttributeError: 'Entry' object has no attribute 'yview'

Tags: python, tkinter

A am trying to add a scroll bar that scrolls downwards but it doesn't work. though it works when i do xview so I'm not sure why its not working for yview.

sry for bad grammar.

```
round_desc_scroll=tk.Scrollbar(root,orient='vertical',command=round_desc_label.yview)
round_desc_scroll.pack(side=tk.RIGHT,fill=tk.Y)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/AMIN ALI/zorc save after scroll.py", line 134, in <module>
    round_desc_scroll=tk.Scrollbar(root, orient='vertical',command=round_desc_label.yview)
AttributeError: 'Entry' object has no attribute 'yview'
```

Comment: yes, `Entry` does not have that method, if you want some text widget that can also scroll on the y axis use [`Text`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/text.html)

Comment: does it only not work with y view then why does it work with x view

Comment: yes, it only has x view, why? because Entry is not supposed to be a multiline text widget, if you want to have multiline text use `Text` widget

Comment: i see that makes sense

Comment: wait do u not even  need a scrollbar to scroll on a text widget

Comment: not necessarily as you may have already noticed, but adding it can still be a nice feature even if most of the time it will be only a decoration, it certainly helps getting to the end faster since you can just drag the scrollbar to the end pretty quickly or otherwise if the text is large it can be faster to approximately get to some places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error says, an `Entry` widget does not have a `yview` method. This is because the `Entry` widget can only ever display a single line of text. It has an `xview` method to scroll in the horizontal direction because the data can be longer than the widget.

If you need to display or allow the user to input multiline data, you need to use a `Text` widget which supports scrolling in both directions.